# Stamps.com integration - shipping emails not being sent

Tags: email, shipment

We have a Magento store that we've linked to Stamps.com to print out the shipping labels. We've almost got it working properly. However, we have an issue with Shipping emails.

We want to send them out through Magento, as the Stamps.com emails don't get branded correctly. If we do this inside Magento by opening the order and clicking the Ship button, the emails are sent as expected. They go to the customer, and there's a copy sent via BCC to the address specified.

When we use Stamps.com, though, the customer emails aren't getting sent out. The order is being updated correctly with the right status and with the tracking number; and Magento is sending out a tracking email - but it's sending it directly to the BCC address. There's no customer copy sent, and the To: address in the sent email is the address it should be BCCing to.

Is there a setting email I've missed for this? I've looked everywhere I can, but I've not been able to find anything that looks like it would help for this.

Comment: Have you tried contacting Stamps technical support first?  They will know their product better than the community.  Perhaps their Magento integration disables the emails from being sent?

Comment: @Axel - thanks for the suggestion. I've called them, and they said that everything is fine from their point of view - their client is posting back to Magento as expected, and it's Magento that's not sending the Shipping confirmation properly. It's as though Magento is assuming that Stamps.com will have sent the client an email directly, and so all that's left is for it to email the BCC address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue looks like it's coming from the Stamps.com configuration files.

In `ShippingZSettings.php`, there's a configuration setting:

```
define("Magento_SendsShippingEmail",0);
```

That controls whether Magento sends the shipping email - it's 0 by default, which turns the Magento email off.